# Menú/submenú desplegable no funciona - HTML CSS jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menú

He creado un menú que se despliega en `hover` sobre el ícono y submenú, lo mismo sobre el enlace **Servicios**. La idea es que se despliegue en `hover` en pantallas grandes y clickeando, en pantallas pequeñas. Pero no funciona.

Código:

```js
/* Determina si mostrar o no el icono para desplegar */
function ponerDespliegue(){
  if($(window).width() > 979){ return; }  
  // Pongo todo a cerrado
  $(".nivel1, .nivel1, .itemN2 > a > .hijos").css({"display":"none"});
  $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_close");
  $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_open");
  $(".hijos").addClass("hijos_close");
  // Mostrar iconos
  var hermanos = null;
  $(".nivel3").each(function(i, e) {
    hermanos = $(this).parent().find(".hijos").eq(0);
    if($(hermanos).length){
      $(hermanos).css({"display":"block"});
    }
  });
}
/* Función que abre el nivel inferior */
function toggleResponsivo(nodo, nivel){

  event.preventDefault(); 
  var superior = null;

  if(nivel == '1'){
    superior = $(nodo).parent().parent();
    $(superior).find(".nivel2").eq(0).toggle(function(){
      var cambio = $(this).parent().siblings("a").eq(0).find(".hijos").eq(0);
      if( $(this).css("display") == "block" ){
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_close");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_open");
      }
      else{
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_open");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_close");
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    $(nodo).parent().parent().find(".nivel3").eq(0).toggle(function(){
      var cambio = $(this).siblings("a").eq(0).find(".hijos").eq(0);
      if( $(this).css("display") == "block" ){
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_close");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_open");
      }
      else{
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_open");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_close");
      }
    });    
  }
}
/* LLAMADAS EN CARGAS */
$(document).ready(function(e){
  ponerDespliegue(); 
  $("#pull").unbind().click(function(){
    $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_close");
    $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_open");
    $(".hijos").addClass("hijos_close");
    $("#menu").toggle();
    if($(window).width() < 980){
      $(".nivel2, .nivel3").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
$(window).resize(function(e) {
  ponerDespliegue(); 
  if($(window).width() > 979){
    $(".nivel2, .nivel3").removeAttr("style");
    $(".hijos").css("display","none");
  }
});
```

```css
/* GENERAL */

/*- General -*/
#menu{ background-color:#000; height:220px; clear:both; }
#menu > ul{ margin:0 auto; height: 500px; z-index:9999; }
#menu li{ position:relative; }
#menu a{ font-size:112.5%; height:100%; line-height:30px; padding:0px 13px; display:block; }
#menu a,
#menu a:visited{ color:#FFF; }
#menu a:hover,
#menu li.activo > a{ color:#a88c30 !important; opacity:1; cursor:pointer; }

.menu_fixed{ position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; margin:0px; z-index:8888; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; }

.hijos{ position: absolute; top:1px; right: 5px; display:block; height:22px; width:22px; outline:1px solid; text-align:center; font-size:22px; line-height:1em; font-weight:bold; color:#a88c30; background-color:#FFF; }
.hijos_close:after{ content:'+'; margin-top:2px; }
.hijos_open:after{ content:'-'; margin-top:2px; }

/*- Nivel 1 -*/
.nivel1{ }

/*- Nivel 2 -*/
.nivel2{ background-color:red; }

/*- Nivel 3 -*/
.nivel3{ background-color:red; }

/* MENÚ COMÚN TABLET + MOVIL */
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 980px) {

  /* General */
  #menu{ display:none; height:0px; width:280px; position:absolute; right:0px; top:63px; }
  #menu > ul { background-color:#000; width:100%; }

  .hijos{ display:block; }

  #pull{ width:96%; display:inline-block; position: relative; line-height:30px; color:#FFF; text-align:left; margin-left: 40px; }
  #pull:after { content:""; background: url('../images/comun/nav-icon.png') no-repeat; background-size:cover; width: 40px; height: 40px; position: absolute; right: 30px; top:-12px; }
}

/* PC */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {

  /*- General -*/
  .hijos{ display:none; }

  /*- Nivel 1 -*/
  .nivel1 > li{ vertical-align:top; border-right:1px solid #FFF; margin-right:-4px; }
  .nivel1 > li:last-child{ border-right:none; }
  .nivel1 > li:hover .nivel2{ display:block; }

  /*- Nivel 2 -*/
  .nivel2{ display:none; position: absolute; top:30px; }
  .nivel2 > li:hover .nivel3{ display:block; }

  /*- Nivel 3 -*/
  .nivel3{ display:none; position: absolute; top:0px; left: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="menuHamburguesa">
  <img src="images/comun/menu-ico.png" alt="">
</a>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul class="nivel1">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php" class="link_nivel1">
        INICIO
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="labelle.php" class="link_nivel1">
        LA BELLE
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        SERVICIOS
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nivel2">
        <li><a>PELUQUERIA</a></li>
        <li><a>ESTETICA</a></li>
        <li><a>TRATAMIENTO FACIAL</a></li>
        <li><a>TRATAMIENTO CORPORAL</a></li>
        <li><a>LASER</a></li>
        <li><a>MAQUILLAJE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
      PROMOCIONES
      <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        RESERVAR
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        NOTICIAS
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        CONTACTO
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para serte sincero, no entiendo bien tu código, no es muy legible, así que en primera instancia te recomendaría escribir un código limpio. Te apuesto mi vida que en 1 año no eres capaz de entender lo que has escrito.

Ahora, yendo directo al grano, lo único que he agregado es lo siguiente. En la función `toggleResponsivo` solo he alternado la clase `open` para las listas internas de modo que se abran:

```
var superior = $(nodo).parent().parent();
superior.find('ul').toggleClass('open');
```

Y en CSS:

```
.link_nivel1 + .nivel2 {
  display: none;
}

.link_nivel1 + .nivel2.open {
  display: block;
}
```

Otro cambio que he realizado es simplemente poner en la media query para pantalla grande, que toda clase que empiece con `.link_nivel` y que sea hermana una `ul` deba hacerse visible al hacer hover sobre el hermano anterior:

```
a[class^='link_nivel']:hover + ul {
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Fíjate que también le doy un `z-index` para que no se refleje el texto de la lista principal.

**Ejemplo**

```js
/* Determina si mostrar o no el icono para desplegar */
function ponerDespliegue() {
  if ($(window).width() > 979) {
    return;
  }
  // Pongo todo a cerrado
  $(".itemN2 > a > .hijos").css({
    "display": "none"
  });
  $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_close");
  $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_open");
  $(".hijos").addClass("hijos_close");
  
  // Mostrar iconos
  var hermanos = null;
  $(".nivel3").each(function(i, e) {
    hermanos = $(this).parent().find(".hijos").eq(0);
    if ($(hermanos).length) {
      $(hermanos).css({
        "display": "block"
      });
    }
  });
}
/* Función que abre el nivel inferior */
function toggleResponsivo(nodo, nivel) {

  //event.preventDefault(); // no tienes un parámetro event
  var superior = $(nodo).parent().parent();
  superior.find('ul').toggleClass('open');
  
  if (nivel == '1') {
    $(superior).find(".nivel2").eq(0).toggle(function() {
      var cambio = $(this).parent().siblings("a").eq(0).find(".hijos").eq(0);
      if ($(this).css("display") == "block") {
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_close");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_open");
      } else {
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_open");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_close");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(nodo).parent().parent().find(".nivel3").eq(0).toggle(function() {
      var cambio = $(this).siblings("a").eq(0).find(".hijos").eq(0);
      if ($(this).css("display") == "block") {
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_close");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_open");
      } else {
        $(cambio).removeClass("hijos_open");
        $(cambio).addClass("hijos_close");
      }
    });
  }
}
/* LLAMADAS EN CARGAS */
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  ponerDespliegue();
  $("#pull").unbind().click(function() {
    $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_close");
    $(".hijos").removeClass("hijos_open");
    $(".hijos").addClass("hijos_close");
    $("#menu").toggle();
    if ($(window).width() < 980) {
      $(".nivel2, .nivel3").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  
  $('#menuHamburguesa').on('click', function () {
    $('#menu').toggle();
  });
  
});
$(window).resize(function(e) {
  ponerDespliegue();
  if ($(window).width() > 979) {
    $(".nivel2, .nivel3").removeAttr("style");
    $(".hijos").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
/* GENERAL */
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*- General -*/

#menu {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 220px;
  clear: both;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu>ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#menu li {
  position: relative;
}

#menu a {
  font-size: 112.5%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 13px;
  display: block;
}

#menu a,
#menu a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
}

#menu a:hover,
#menu li.activo>a {
  color: #a88c30 !important;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 8888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.hijos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a88c30;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.hijos_close:after {
  content: '+';
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.hijos_open:after {
  content: '-';
  margin-top: 2px;
}


/*- Nivel 1 -*/

.nivel1 {}


/*- Nivel 2 -*/

.nivel2 {
  background-color: red;
}


/*- Nivel 3 -*/

.nivel3 {
  background-color: red;
}


/* MENÚ COMÚN TABLET + MOVIL */

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  /* General */
  #menu {
    display: none;
    //height: 0px;
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 63px;
  }
  #menu>ul {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hijos {
    display: block;
  }
  #pull {
    width: 96%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
  #pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('../images/comun/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: -12px;
  }
  .link_nivel1 + .nivel2 {
    display: none;
  }

  .link_nivel1 + .nivel2.open {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* PC */

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  #menu {
    display: block;
  }
  a[class^='link_nivel']:hover + ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  /*- General -*/
  .hijos {
    display: none;
  }
  /*- Nivel 1 -*/
  .nivel1>li {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
  .nivel1>li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
  .nivel1>li:hover .nivel2 {
    display: block;
  }
  /*- Nivel 2 -*/
  .nivel2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
  }
  .nivel2>li:hover .nivel3 {
    display: block;
  }
  /*- Nivel 3 -*/
  .nivel3 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
  }
  #menuHamburguesa:hover + #menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="menuHamburguesa">
  <img src="images/comun/menu-ico.png" alt="">
</a>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul class="nivel1">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php" class="link_nivel1">
        INICIO
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="labelle.php" class="link_nivel1">
        LA BELLE
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        SERVICIOS
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nivel2">
        <li><a>PELUQUERIA</a></li>
        <li><a>ESTETICA</a></li>
        <li><a>TRATAMIENTO FACIAL</a></li>
        <li><a>TRATAMIENTO CORPORAL</a></li>
        <li><a>LASER</a></li>
        <li><a>MAQUILLAJE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
      PROMOCIONES
      <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        RESERVAR
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        NOTICIAS
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link_nivel1">
        CONTACTO
        <span class="hijos" onclick="toggleResponsivo(this, 2)"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```